Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''.The exception'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Magazin_Online.Data.AppDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Magazin_Online.Data.AppDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
https://github.com/TeisRaul/MagazinOnline.git
Here is my project, i don't know where the problem is
Startup.cs:
using Magazin_Online.Data;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Magazin_Online
{

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseRouting();
            //app.UseSession();

            //Authentication & Authorization
            //app.UseAuthentication();
            //app.UseAuthorization();

            //app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Movies}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}

AppDbContext.cs:
using Magazin_Online.Models;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Magazin_Online.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProdusComanda>().HasKey(pc => new
            {
                pc.ProdusId,
                pc.ComandaId
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProdusComanda>().HasOne(p => p.Produs).WithMany(pc => pc.ProdusComanda).HasForeignKey(p => p.ProdusId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProdusComanda>().HasOne(c => c.Comanda).WithMany(pc => pc.ProdusComanda).HasForeignKey(c => c.ComandaId);


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Produs> Produse { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comanda> Comenzi { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Utilizator> Utilizatori { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Admin> Admini { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProdusComanda> ProdusComanda { get; set; }


    }
}

appsetings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Data Source=DESKTOP-O5OCL36\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Magazin-Online-db;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

AppDbInitializer.cs
using Magazin_Online.Data.Enums;
using Magazin_Online.Data;
using Magazin_Online.Models;

namespace MagazinOnline.Data
{
    public class AppDbInitializer
    {
        public static void Seed(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>();

                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                if (!context.Admini.Any())
                {
                    context.Admini.AddRange(new Admin
                    {
                        Username = "admin",
                        Password = "admin"
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                if (!context.Utilizatori.Any())
                {
                    context.Utilizatori.AddRange(new Utilizator
                    {
                        Nume = "Teis",
                        Prenume = "Raul",
                        Email = "teisraul@yahoo.co.uk",
                        Parola = "parola",
                        Adresa = "Str. Mihai Eminescu, nr. 1",
                        Oras = Orase.Oradea,
                        Telefon = "0723456789",
                        AdminId = 1
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                if (!context.Produse.Any())
                {
                    context.Produse.AddRange(new List<Produs>
                    {
                        new Produs
                        {
                            Denumire = "Laptop",
                            Categorie = CategorieProdus.Electronice_si_electrocasnice,
                            Pret = 3000,
                            NumarBucati = 3,
                            Imagine = "laptop.jpg",
                            Descriere = "Laptop performant",
                            Orase = Orase.Oradea,
                            UtilizatorId = 1
                        }
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


your code looks correct. just make sure you have set the appsettings.json "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Copy if newer" in the properties. debug the code and see if the connecting string is correct or not. for a test temporarily create an instance of DbContext manually in your startup code to test if the issue is related to dependency injection or the DbContext itself.
